# jQuery Dialog Open (more than once)?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, dialog

I found some jQuery code online for the jQuery Dialog and it works great. The problem I am having is when I click on the linked image to open dialog it opens like it should but if I close the dialog and click the linked image again it will not reopen the jQuery Dialog.

Here is the jQuery code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
       $('#gravatarprofilemoreinfoshow').click(function(){
           $('#gravatarprofilemoreinfo').dialog({
               modal:true,
               resizable: false,
               draggable: true,
               width: '486px',
               height: 'auto',
               hide: 'size',
               autoOpen: true,
               buttons:{ "Close": function() { $(this).dialog("close"); } },
               close: function(ev, ui) { $(this).remove(); }
           });
       });
   });
```

The HTML markup is:

```
<a href="#" id="gravatarprofilemoreinfoshow" rel="/somelink" >
<img class="profileimgright profileimgframe" alt="Profile Image" src="/url/to/image" />
</a>
```

How can I adjust the code? Also is there a way to alter the code so it does not depend on unique id's?

Reason I ask is I would like to use the jQuery code above across my site to show different information but the code above requires a unique name (sorry not sure what they call it in jQuery) and want the code to be reusable across my website.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should delete the line

```
close: function(ev, ui) { $(this).remove(); }
```

problem is that it removes the dialog and contents after close, so you are not able to use it on second click. Take a look at [jQuery Remove](http://api.jquery.com/remove/)

Also, to reuse use this code, you could do following. Declare the method that Registers Dialog On Click. This method would be passed selectors of the image and dialog

```
function registerDialogOnImageClick($image, $dialog){
      $image.click(function(){
           $dialog.dialog({
               modal:true,
               resizable: false,
               draggable: true,
               width: '486px',
               height: 'auto',
               hide: 'size',
               autoOpen: true,
               buttons:{ "Close": function() { $(this).dialog("close"); } },
           });
       });
   }
```

this code could be called from anywhere, passing selectors of image and dialog

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   registerDialogOnImageClick($('#gravatarprofilemoreinfoshow'), $('#gravatarprofilemoreinfo');
});
```

Comment: Thanks @archil. Perfectly explained to me and problem solved :) Thanks PHPLOVER